# Convert time to decimal equivalent it Excel / Emacs

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, emacs, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a chart of my times for my runs (e.g. 25:30, for 25 minutes and 30 seconds). 
How could I convert this "analog" time to the decimal equivalent (e.g. 25.5 minutes)?
The problem is I can never get it to work with anything above 24.

I would like to be able to do this in Emacs and/or Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Format Cells` and select `Custom` and scroll down to `[h]:mm:ss`.  This will allow you to go over 24 hours (particularly useful if you want to sum your times, as this will not restart counting at 24 hours).

Times:

```
12:00:00
3:30:00
10:45:00
1:04:00
```

`sum = 27:19`

Once you've got your times entered in, using the `mm:ss` convention, sum them, and then convert the cell formatting of the sum cell to `Number`, which will give you a fraction of 24 hours (so if your times added to 24:00, the fraction would be 1.00, which, multiplied by 24 gets you 24.00).

`=1.14` (since the "time" 27:19 would be 114% of a day) * 24

`=27.19`